# Three Layer CSS Menu within Salesforce VF page

Tags: html, css, salesforce, visualforce

I am building a VF page for the purpose of easily navigating custom reports. I am just starting to learn code and could use an extra set of eyes to help identify my errors.

The two issues being:

1. The third layer of the menu is not appearing upon hover (I have tried many combinations of css code)
2. The initial link opens in the iFrame, but the 2nd later links open as separate tabs.

   ---

**CSS**

```
.top head {font-size: 40px; text-align: center; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}

.nav ul {list-style: none; margin: 0px; font-family: verdana, sans-serif; text-align: center;}

.nav li {float:left; width:200px background-color:#444444; text-align: center; 
          boarder-right:1px solid white; position:relative; height:30px; line-height:30px;}

.nav li ul li {float:none; width:200px; text-align:center; padding-left:5px; boarder-tip:1px solid white;}

.nav a {text-decoration:none; color:black; text-align: center;}
.nav li ul {position:absolute; top:30px; left:0; visibility:hidden;}

.nav li:hover {background-color:yellow;}
.nav li:hover ul {visibility:visible;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">

<ul> 
    <li>  
        <a> Summary </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="www" target="theIframe">Volume </a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="www" target="theIframe">Overall</a></li>
        </ul>
            <li><a href="www" target="theIframe"> ASP </a></li>
        </ul>

</ul>
</div> 

<br/>

<iframe src="www" scrolling="true" id="theIframe" width="90%" align="center"/>
```

Comment: You have only two level menu and you missed closing `</li>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't try, but if you keep your code clean, and semantic, it will be work. I mean now, you code has so many unclosed elements, and it is quite possible this is why don't work's your code

Comment: Do you mean I should take out some of the css styling or put them into separate documents?